# Terraform plan with 1Password provider fails with rpc error unavailable desc transport is closing

Tags: terraform, 1password

After adding some new secrets to Terraform using the 1Password provider, we saw an error without much helpful output.

```sh
$ terraform plan

...
Error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
Error: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
...
```

Terraform provider:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    onepassword = {
      source = "anasinnyk/onepassword"
      version = "~> 1.2.1"
    }
  }
  required_version = "~> 0.13"
}
```

Terraform yml:

```yaml
data "onepassword_item_password" "search_cloud_id" {
   name  = "Azure Elastic Cloud ID"
   vault = data.onepassword_vault.vault_name.id
}

data "onepassword_item_password" "search_api_key" {
   name  = "Azure Elastic Cloud API key"
   vault = data.onepassword_vault.vault_name.id
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "search" {
   metadata {
     name      = "search"
     namespace = kubernetes_namespace.production.id
   }
   data = {
     "ELASTICSEARCH_CLOUD_ID" = data.onepassword_item_password.api_search_cloud_id.password
     "ELASTICSEARCH_API_KEY"  = data.onepassword_item_password.api_search_api_key.password
   }
   type = "Opaque"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We managed to get some useful output by removing one `data` reference at a time, which lead to the errors printing:

```sh
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1: [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x147d1bd]
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1:
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1: goroutine 194 [running]:
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1: github.com/anasinnyk/terraform-provider-1password/onepassword.resourceItemPasswordRead(0x19418a0, 0xc0004ac540, 0xc000096f80, 0x173d040, 0xc0007ac740, 0xc0003bce40, 0xc000119910, 0x100c9b8)
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1:  github.com/anasinnyk/terraform-provider-1password/onepassword/resource_item_password.go:75 +0x18d
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1: github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema.(*Resource).read(0xc0004613f0, 0x1941820, 0xc000384300, 0xc000096f80, 0x173d040, 0xc0007ac740, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1:  github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.0.0/helper/schema/resource.go:288 +0x1ec
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1: github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema.(*Resource).ReadDataApply(0xc0004613f0, 0x1941820, 0xc000384300, 0xc000304b80, 0x173d040, 0xc0007ac740, 0xc0007ac740, 0xc000304b80, 0x0, 0x0)
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1:  github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.0.0/helper/schema/resource.go:489 +0xff
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1: github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/internal/helper/plugin.(*GRPCProviderServer).ReadDataSource(0xc00026e6a0, 0x1941820, 0xc000384300, 0xc0003842c0, 0xc00026e6a0, 0xc00026e6b0, 0x185a058)
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1:  github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.0.0/internal/helper/plugin/grpc_provider.go:1102 +0x4c5
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1: github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/internal/tfplugin5._Provider_ReadDataSource_Handler.func1(0x1941820, 0xc000384300, 0x17dcd60, 0xc0003842c0, 0xc000384300, 0x1773c80, 0xc0004ac401, 0xc000304640)
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1:  github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.0.0/internal/tfplugin5/tfplugin5.pb.go:3348 +0x86
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1: github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/plugin.Serve.func3.1(0x19418e0, 0xc0003d4480, 0x17dcd60, 0xc0003842c0, 0xc000304620, 0xc000304640, 0xc0007c8ba0, 0x11b81c8, 0x17c7a20, 0xc0003d4480)
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1:  github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.0.0/plugin/serve.go:76 +0x87
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1: github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/internal/tfplugin5._Provider_ReadDataSource_Handler(0x17fdb60, 0xc00026e6a0, 0x19418e0, 0xc0003d4480, 0xc0004ac4e0, 0xc00000d080, 0x19418e0, 0xc0003d4480, 0xc000010090, 0x90)
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1:  github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.0.0/internal/tfplugin5/tfplugin5.pb.go:3350 +0x14b
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1: google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC(0xc00027ae00, 0x1949c60, 0xc000103380, 0xc00018e000, 0xc00020acf0, 0x1e49910, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1:  google.golang.org/grpc@v1.30.0/server.go:1171 +0x50a
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1: google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream(0xc00027ae00, 0x1949c60, 0xc000103380, 0xc00018e000, 0x0)
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1:  google.golang.org/grpc@v1.30.0/server.go:1494 +0xccd
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1: google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2(0xc0000382e0, 0xc00027ae00, 0x1949c60, 0xc000103380, 0xc00018e000)
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1:  google.golang.org/grpc@v1.30.0/server.go:834 +0xa1
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1: created by google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1
2021-08-27T15:34:29.367+0930 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1:  google.golang.org/grpc@v1.30.0/server.go:832 +0x204
2021-08-27T15:34:29.368+0930 [WARN]  plugin.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"
2021/08/27 15:34:29 [ERROR] eval: *terraform.evalReadDataRefresh, err: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
2021/08/27 15:34:29 [ERROR] eval: *terraform.evalReadDataRefresh, err: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
2021/08/27 15:34:29 [ERROR] eval: *terraform.evalReadDataRefresh, err: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
2021/08/27 15:34:29 [ERROR] eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
2021-08-27T15:34:29.369+0930 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/plugins/registry.terraform.io/anasinnyk/onepassword/1.2.1/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-onepassword_v1.2.1 pid=17549 error="exit status 2"
2021/08/27 15:34:29 [ERROR] eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
2021/08/27 15:34:29 [TRACE] [walkRefresh] Exiting eval tree: data.onepassword_item_password.search_api_key
2021/08/27 15:34:29 [ERROR] eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
2021/08/27 15:34:29 [TRACE] vertex "data.onepassword_item_password.search_api_key": visit complete
2021/08/27 15:34:29 [TRACE] vertex "data.onepassword_item_password.search_api_key": dynamic subgraph encountered errors
2021/08/27 15:34:29 [TRACE] vertex "data.onepassword_item_password.search_api_key": visit complete
2021/08/27 15:34:29 [TRACE] vertex "data.onepassword_item_password.search_api_key (expand)": dynamic subgraph encountered errors
2021/08/27 15:34:29 [TRACE] vertex "data.onepassword_item_password.search_api_key (expand)": visit complete
2021/08/27 15:34:29 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes\"] (close)" errored, so skipping
2021/08/27 15:34:29 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/anasinnyk/onepassword\"] (close)" errored, so skipping
2021/08/27 15:34:29 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "root" errored, so skipping
2021-08-27T15:34:29.501+0930 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin exited
2021-08-27T15:34:29.502+0930 [WARN]  plugin.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"
2021-08-27T15:34:29.507+0930 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes/1.13.3/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-kubernetes_v1.13.3_x4 pid=17673
2021-08-27T15:34:29.507+0930 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin exited



!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! TERRAFORM CRASH !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Terraform crashed! This is always indicative of a bug within Terraform.
A crash log has been placed at "crash.log" relative to your current
working directory. It would be immensely helpful if you could please
report the crash with Terraform[1] so that we can fix this.

When reporting bugs, please include your terraform version. That
information is available on the first line of crash.log. You can also
get it by running 'terraform --version' on the command line.

SECURITY WARNING: the "crash.log" file that was created may contain
sensitive information that must be redacted before it is safe to share
on the issue tracker.

[1]: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! TERRAFORM CRASH !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

This led us to find that one of our team members managed to create two 1Password entries with the same name in the same vault.

After deleting the duplicate entry in 1Password, `terraform plan` ran without error again.